# Using a switch or defining an array of functions - which is faster?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, switch-statement

Which of these two programs run faster? The first is an array of pointers to two functions that re-assign a variable, the second is a switch of two cases that re-assign the variable in the same way.

## 1:

```
#include <iostream>

void w (int &z);
void y (int &z);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    void (*p[2]) (int &a) = {w,y};
    int s = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        p[s](s);
    }
    return 0;
}

void w (int &z) {
    z = 1;
}

void y (int &z) {
    z = 0;
}
```

## 2:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int s = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        switch (s) {
            case 0:
                s = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                s = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In general, does the program run faster if you use an array of pointers to functions instead of defining a switch statement if you know at compile time which instructions to perform depending on the current value of the variable? Or is the switch statement faster? Or are they both just as fast?

Comment: Did you measure yourself already (with optimization levels on)?

Comment: That first example kind of makes my skin crawl...

Comment: The two programs you show are not really equivalent, they are not strictly comparable.

Comment: The `switch` version is definitely more readable, which is in many cases more important than (potential and not guaranteed) optimization gains you could get from the first version.

Comment: They are very likely to be equivalent, performance-wise. An optimizing compiler will transform a suitable switch statement into a jump table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think switch statements will be the faster, because function pointers have the overhead of the look up of the function and the function call. A switch is just a jump table straight.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement will be faster, and a heck of a lot easier to understand. At least, in this case. And likely in most cases.

In this case it will be faster because the compiler can completely drop the whole loop. It's obvious that all of the code only has an effect on local variables and so it can be eliminated without changing the observable behavior of the program.

And this highlights why the `switch` statement will generally be faster. If there are a lot of cases, it will be implemented with a jump table and the compiler has all the information right at its fingertips and can do all kinds of tricks to drop code or move it around for speed reasons.

With the function pointer version, the compiler has to be smart enough to realize that you're initializing the array with function pointers and then never changing it or passing its address to anything so anything else could change it. It also then has to look inside all the functions being called and realize they have no effects on anything but the reference being passed in. That's a **lot** to ask.

And even worse, the function pointer version is really difficult for a human to understand. And if you don't care about that, why aren't you writing it in assembly language or (even better) in raw processor opcodes?